# SSMS Invalid column name

Tags: javascript, sql-server, sql-server-2017

I have this table here:
[image]

and the SessionId is autoincremented.
When I try adding a session:

```
srDataAccessManager.addSession = function(title,speakerId,cbfSuccess,cbfError){
    _makeSQLRequest("INSERT INTO dbo.Session (Title, SpeakerId, SessionState) values(" + title+ "," + speakerId+ ",'Created')",cbfSuccess,cbfError);
}

function _makeSQLRequest(sqlString,cbfSuccess,cbfError){
    sql.close();

    sql.connect(config,(err)=>{
        if(err) 
            cbfError(err);
        else{ 
            var request = new sql.Request();
            request.query(sqlString, (err,result) =>
            {
                if(err)
                    cbfError(err);
                else                    
                    cbfSuccess(result);
            });
        }
    });

}
```

I get this error:

[image]

I don't understand where this error is coming from.  Is it because i didn't add the id in the insert string? I didn't enter the id as I thought that I don't need any when the SMMS takes care of the id. I already checked the datatypes of my input and it is a string and a int so I doubt it that its because of the data types. Any suggestions?

Comment: Does SessionId have the [identity property](https://learn.microsoft.com/en-us/sql/t-sql/statements/create-table-transact-sql-identity-property?view=sql-server-2017)?

Answer (score 0):

Your `INSERT` statement looks wrong to me. I believe you should have single quotes around the `Title` parameter:

```
_makeSQLRequest("INSERT INTO dbo.Session (Title, SpeakerId, SessionState) 
values('" + title+ "'," + speakerId+ ",'Created')",cbfSuccess,cbfError);
```

Notice the single quote before the first closing double quote, and the single quote before the first comma.